# Simple Directed Graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In graph theory, would a graph with edges $(u, v)$ and $(v, u)$ connecting vertices $v$ and $u$ be considered a directed simple graph?  For example: would this graph be considered a simple directed graph?

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is a simple directed graph (it has neither loops nor multiple arrows with the same source and target). However it is *not* a directed *acyclic* graph, because $u,v$ (or $1,3$ in your picture) form a directed cycle. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Types_of_directed_graphs) for a description of many directed graph types.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!